# When to use Float vs Double in JAVA code?

Tags: java, double, computer-science

Can someone show me an example of example how I could use Double in the following code?

```java
    public class HelloWorld {
       public static void main(String[] args) {

           System.out.println("Hello, World!");

           int myFirstNumber = (5+10) + (6*8);//Declaring an integer myFirstNumber
           int mySecondNumber = 10;
           int myThirdNumber = 3;
           int myTotal = myFirstNumber + mySecondNumber + myThirdNumber;

           System.out.println(myFirstNumber);//prints variable myFirstNumber
           System.out.println("myFirstNumber ");//
           System.out.println(myTotal);
       }

    }
```

Comment: What is 10 divided by 4? If you use `int` to code that answer, your result will be `2`. But the answer should probably be `2.5`, don't you think. So **any** time you need non-integer numbers, use `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Use either `float` or `double` (or their boxed counterparts, `Float` and `Double`) when you need to deal with non-integer values. The code you posted has no apparent need for that, so it's hard to answer your question. But one possibility would be if you wanted to compute, say, the average of the three numbers:

```
public class HelloWorld { public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");

   int myFirstNumber = (5+10) + (6*8);//Declaring an integer myFirstNumber
   int mySecondNumber = 10;
   int myThirdNumber = 3;
   int myTotal = myFirstNumber + mySecondNumber + myThirdNumber;
   float average = myTotal / 3.0f;

   System.out.println(myFirstNumber);//prints variable myFirstNumber
   System.out.println("myFirstNumber ");//
   System.out.println(myTotal);
   System.out.println(average);
}
```

As to when to use `float` vs. `double` (the title of your question), use `double` when you can tolerate less rounding error than you get with `float`.